# Is there a way to download a jar from remote repository and copy to a directory using maven commandline?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using maven-dependnecy-plugin 3.1.1 and trying to download a jar from a remote repository(which is not the maven central repo) and copy it to a custom output directory.

Was able to download using older versions but couldn't find a way to do it with the newer version.

Comment: What is the purpose of manually copying it instead of simply adding it to the classpath?

Comment: Need the jar files to be extracted as part of shell script which can't have any pom and that jar will be run at a different time.

Comment: "Was able to download using older versions but couldn't find a way to do it with the newer version", which is that older version. Is it Maven older version ?

Comment: the dependency-plugin older version 2.1

Comment: Sharing the code snippet would help to answer in better way. In maven, remote repository could be any repository as defined in settings.xml file and from that sense, it hardly matters whether it is central repository or not. Also, I can see from following link that it should work as expected (3.1.1 plugin documentation): https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html